# Did I really Install GIT 2.0.1?

Tags: unix, git

I'm following instructions from http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-update-latest-version-git-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/

But when I type in "git --version", I'm seeing:

```
git version 1.8.4
```

Prior to this, I'd installed GitHub Mac and allowed it to install git. Is it possible that I have 2 git versions installed?  If so, how do I make sure that I'm actually using GIT 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably now have two versions of git installed. If you type

```
which git
```

in the Terminal, it should tell you which one is in your PATH. For me, the above command returns

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

The instructions you mention apparently install another copy of git here: `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

You need to add this new location to your PATH variable. To do so, navigate to your home directory and edit your .bash_profile by typing

```
cd
edit .bash_profile
```

and add the following line to it:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

Save the file, open a new Terminal window and try typing `git --version` again. Hopefully, it should now run the newest version.